# Can we get Mathjax on Software Engineering?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

While I realize that it might not be used as often as it is on Math.SE, it would be nice to be able to use inline Latex every now and then to illustrate an algorithm or a math function. Would this be possible?

Comment: I'm marking this [status-declined] for completeness since you found a decent workaround.

Comment: We're programmers, decent workarounds is what we do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but I'm not sure that it's necessary. I can't recall any situations where we could've really used an accurate math representation.

But, I could be totally wrong. :)

Typically requests like this need to come with a list of situations where the feature would be genuinely useful. Do you have any particular questions in mind?

Comment: This one springs to mind.

http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118690/complex-numbers-in-programming

Comment: Scratch that, hunting around the math site found me this http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: Anything that could help expressing the needs of a problem such as an algorithm or a data structure should be welcome I believe.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to point out that according to the faq this site deals with

> algorithm and data structure concepts

These are problems that tend to be reduced to some kind of math problem and many times are best expressed with the help of mathematical notation.

I looked at the solution proposed of using images linked from http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

but for anything non-trivial this really would be a big PITA.

For instance, I wrote [this solution for a problem from Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/186081/73652).

Answer (score 3):

I agree that Math formatting could be a very nice feature, as it is available in numerous SE sites.

It is helpful to formalize some problems, and I personnaly do not understand the workaround that is suggested.

For example in this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133738/how-to-unit-test-computational-libraries-when-the-return-type-is-double) I'd have preferred to explain my solution mathematically without actually giving the code. And I would have like to be able to provide the formula for computing the performances: $p_t = \frac{p_{t+1}}{p_t}$